# Get element node at caret position (in contentEditable)

Tags: javascript, dom, webkit, contenteditable, caret

Let's say I have some HTML code like this:

```
<body contentEditable="true">
   <h1>Some heading text here</h1>
   <p>Some text here</p>
</body>
```

Now the caret (the blinking cursor) is blinking inside the `<h1>` element, let's say in the word `"|heading"`.

How can I get the element the caret is in with JavaScript? Here I would like to get node name: `"h1"`.

This needs to work only in WebKit (it's embedded in an application). It should preferably also work for selections.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Firstly, think about *why* you're doing this. If you're trying to stop users from editing certain elements, just set `contenteditable` to false on those elements.

However, it is possible to do what you ask. The code below works in Safari 4 and will return the node the selection is anchored in (i.e. where the user *started to select*, selecting "backwards" will return the end instead of the start) – if you want the element type as a string, just get the `nodeName` property of the returned node. This works for zero-length selections as well (i.e. just a caret position).

```
function getSelectionStart() {
   var node = document.getSelection().anchorNode;
   return (node.nodeType == 3 ? node.parentNode : node);
}
```

Comment: I'm not trying to block the user in any way, I really just need the name of the node so I can update a part of the UI. Thank you for providing the answer, this works great.

Comment: `node.nodeType == 3` would be a better check for a text node.

Comment: Using this in a JavaFX HTMLEditor this works nicely returning the element where the cursor / text caret is placed in a contentEditable section, thanks!  As a side note, document.activeElement is recognised but always returns the body element which isn't very helpful.

Comment: You should use [`window.getSelection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) and not [`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/getSelection)  which is better in most cases

Comment: `window.getSelection().baseNode` will also work. [Related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27241281/104380)