# WYSIWYG editor, structure handling

Tags: html, editor, structure, wysiwyg

I am creating my own wysiwyg editor and I encountered an issue.

As for the editor itself, it is pretty standard, I am using contenteditable iframe with some execcommand buttons for bold text and so on.

Now for my issue, I am not sure how to keep the html structure neat and clean.

For example, user clicks a button to make text he selected floated to the right which takes the selected text and wraps it in

```
  <div style="float: right">selected text</div>
```

. But if the users selects the text multiple times floating it back and forth something like this be the result.

```
<div style="float: right">
   <div style="float: left>
      <div style="float: right">
         selected text
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

, that is of course pretty messy and ugly.

Is there some clean way how to handle this?
(And I don't want to use some third party editors like MCE)

Thanks

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16074358/content-editable-text-editors/16085789#16085789 The answer will be clear.

Comment: I see. Well, I will think about just forcing users to use the bbcode instead, it's not that hard anyway.