# How do I remove HTML in a content editable div if it is under a cursor position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, removeclass

I'm trying to remove the class `.words` from this HTML, whenever it's clicked on it or if a keypress happens over it.

```
<div id="content" contenteditable="true"> Here are <span class="words" id="whatever">some</span> words </div>
```

I've tried

```
$('.words').click(function() { $(this).remove(); });
```

and [more](http://jsfiddle.net/ttMJW/), which work except when I click on another word and cycle over `.words` using left or right key (since it is content editable).  I'd like it to be removed as soon as the the cursor is over the class.  Thanks.

Comment: I think this question has been answered before? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197401/how-can-i-get-the-element-the-caret-is-in-with-javascript-when-using-contentedi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var words = $('.words')[0]    

$('#content').keyup(function(){    
    if (words == getSelectionStart()){
        $(words).remove()   
    }
})

function getSelectionStart() {
   var node = document.getSelection().anchorNode;
   return (node.nodeType == 3 ? node.parentNode : node);
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/nickg1/ttMJW/1/