# Check if "selected text" parent has class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check if currently highlighted/selected text parent has class using JS/jQuery

Ex :

```
<div class="foo">
    <div> This text is selected with the cursor </div>
</div>
```

I tried :

```
if (document.getSelection().parents('.foo').length) {
       console.log("parent has class foo!");
}
```

But this is obviously not a valid solution since document.getSelection().parents is not a function

Comment: Get the `anchorNode` of the Selection object first, that is the node in which the selection begins - and then check what parents _that_ has? (You’ll still have to wrap `$(…)` around the DOM node reference, to be able to call jQuery’s `parents` method.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the selected text with

```
window.getSelection();
```

this has `.anchorNode` and `.focusNode` properties which contains the (text) node that is selected (depending on what exactly is selected)

See [.anchorNode vs .focusNode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27241281/what-is-anchornode-basenode-extentnode-and-focusnode-in-the-object-returned) for the difference.

Giving snippet below.  Note, I've used `mouseup` just to be able to test selecting without changing the focus/selection.  Using `mouseup` would already let you know which element was selected.   OP didn't include how/when their code was to be run, so this just allows a demonstration of the code.

```js
$(document).on("mouseup", () => {

var parent = $(window.getSelection().focusNode).closest("div");
if (parent.is(".foo"))
    console.log("parent has class foo!");
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">
    <p> Select with the mouse </p>
</div>
<div class="notfoo">
    <p> Select with the mouse </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks ! My only issue with this is that my text is wrapped in a div and not in p (sorry, my mistake). So the closest('div') function is being sabotaged

Comment: To summarize I'm building a WYSIWYG component which has 2 windows.
When I write some text, this is what's rendered in the DOM : <div> Some text </div>
and the parent div is the main frame of the window. I need to check if this frame as a certain class to determine in which frame I am

Comment: I'd suggest giving *both* your potential parents the same class, then each a different class, eg `<div class='frame markup'>...</div><div class='frame render'>..</div>` then use `.closest("div.frame").is(".markup")`.

Comment: unfortunately I can't change parents classes because these divs are generated by a JS library I don't fully understand. But I figured out the solution and your first shot helped me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I misread your comment above - thought you said it was in a `p` not a `div`,

Comment: You could do `$("div.foo").addClass("frame")`, no need to change the html

Comment: Or you could do `if (...closest("div.foo").length === 1) ..`

Answer (score 0):

A vanilla JS solution could be:

```js
function checkCSSClass(el, className) {
  return el.classList.contains(className);
}

document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  const parentEl = document.getSelection().focusNode.parentElement.parentElement;
  console.log('has foo class?: ', checkCSSClass(parentEl, 'foo'));
  console.log('has bar class?: ', checkCSSClass(parentEl, 'bar'));
});
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  <div>This text is selected with the cursor </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got what I wanted, using a part of @freedomn-n 's solution

```
$(window.getSelection().focusNode).closest("div").offsetParent().hasClass('foo');
```