# cannot get the content of active div

Tags: jquery, contenteditable

```
<div class="wrap3">
lorem lorem lorem
<div class="inside3 ed" contentEditable>ipsum ipsum ipsum</div>
</div>

<div id="btnsave">Save</div>
```

js

```
$("#btnsave").click(function(){
    var a = document.activeElement.innerText;
    console.log(a);
});
```

Click inside `ed` it becomes active - (blue border arround)

Click on `btnsave` does not give the content of `ed` but the content of entire document.

Comment: `$('.ed').text()` for text only or `$('.ed').html()` for text and other html object

Comment: @guradio, thanks, but I need content of active div. Next click will be on another div

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: @RinoRaj, your updated answer doesn't work. Console is empty. Please check your solution before posting.

Comment: @bonaca check my demo

Comment: @RinoRaj, it's ok. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#btnsave").click(function(){
    var a = $('.ed:focus').text();
});
```

I think this will do.

**Another solution:**

```
$("#btnsave").click(function(){
     $('.lastEdited').text();
     alert($('.lastEdited').text())
});
$("div[contentEditable]").click(function(){
    $("div[contentEditable]").removeClass('lastEdited');
    $(this).addClass('lastEdited');
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/7hn3ojcw/1/)

Comment: Rino, thanks, but I need content of active div. Next click will be on another div.There are many `ed` divs in document.

Comment: No, console is empty with `var a = $('.ed:focus').text();`

Comment: why  you cant use html() instead of  text()

Comment: @safinchacko html() will return the whole content. Consider a sitution like if the OP has some more elements in that div. Then html() wont be nice :)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work correctly with a change of the save element to a button: https://jsfiddle.net/eac5L0aa/1/

```
<div class="wrap3">
lorem lorem lorem
<div class="inside3 ed" contentEditable>ipsum ipsum ipsum</div>

</div>

<button id="btnsave">Save</button>

$("#btnsave").click(function(){
    var a = getSelectionStart();
    console.log(a);
});
function getSelectionStart() {
   var node = document.getSelection().anchorNode;
   console.log(node);
   return (node.nodeType == 3 ? node.parentNode : node);
}
```

Credit to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197401/how-can-i-get-the-element-the-caret-is-in-with-javascript-when-using-contentedi)