# How to get cursor placed element from onclick button using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have contenteditable div in HTML5. I have a `ul li` inside the DOM. When I click on that button I want that cursor placed inside the `li` using javascript. How can I do that?

```html
<span class="mT2 mL10 bullotIcon fR vam" onclick="iconClick(this)">clickButton</span>
<div id="editableEvent" class="w100p  ht70 f13 textField w250 boxSizeBB whiteBg selev grayBdr oA" contenteditable="true" style="height: 100px;">
  <ul>
    <li>dafdsasdsdfasdfd</li>
    <li>dfsfsdfdsfsdfdfdsfsdfsdfdsf</li>
    <li>sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdfsdffdf</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```js
function iconClick(obj){
  if ($('#editableEvent').getSelection) {
     console.log($('#editableEvent').getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode);
  }
}
```

Normally my cursor was inside the content editable div. on click button i want the cursor placed element like 'li' Thanks in advance

Comment: I have tried this only, i dont have idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On click li, I was add one class on it after button clicked i remove that class element

```
  "Li clicked":
           callLiFunction: function (obj){
                $('#editableEvent').find('.liCreated').removeClass('liCreated');
                $(obj).addClass('liCreated');
            }
   "button clicked": 
           funcCallDel : function() {
             $('#editableEvent').find('.liCreated').remove();
           }
```

Thanks for get some idea from you people.

Answer (score 0):

Add code below after you click button.

```
 document.getElementById("editableEvent ul li").style.cursor = "default";
```

Comment: That just sets the style of cursor on the element, it doesn't place the cursor anywhere

Answer (score 0):

To remove an LI that was clicked on, you can use an event's target property to work out what you clicked on then remove it.

Plain JS:

```
document.getElementById('editableEvent').onclick = function(e){
  if(e.target instanceof HTMLLIElement){
    e.target.remove();
  }
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#editableEvent').click(function(e){
  $target = $(e.target);
  if($target.is('li')){
    $target.remove();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just providing links that may help you

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3976125/3979414 - to find the current position in contentEditable text.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1211981/3979414 - to find the cursor mentioned tag

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4232971/3979414 - to remove the corresponding tag

Answer (score 0):

you can also try:

```
 $('li').on('click',function(){

        $(this).remove();
    });
```

Comment: This won't work for dynamically created `<li>`s, for instance, if the `li` is added using the contenteditable by copying and pasting it.

Comment: yes correct, for that issue use $('body').on('click', 'li', function(){});

Comment: and inside function     write  $(this).remove();

Comment: or, better, listen for click events on the `#editableEvent` instead of body as it is not the body's concern

Comment: yes if the div is static then we can use #editableEvent in place of body.  I am giving just a generic solution.