# Get all parent HTML tags from a position within a HTML string

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a simple way to get all the 'parent HTML tags' from a position within a HTML string?

For example:

```
'<div><div>foo</div><p>foo2</p>foo3*caret position here*' : returns '<div>' (the first div)
'<div><div>foo</div><p>foo2*caret position here* : returns '<div><p>' 
'<div><div><div>foo*caret position here* : returns '<div><div><div>'
```

Comment: Are you happy to use a javascript library like jquery or something

Comment: Do you mean a literal string or DOM nodes? The question says "string", but the "caret position" says DOM.

Comment: `parent` is a relative term. `parent HTML tags` of what? A particular `<p>` ? You must be more specific.

Comment: Try with [javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/) and [jquery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/)

Comment: Guessing you are using contentEditable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197401/how-can-i-get-the-element-the-caret-is-in-with-javascript-when-using-contentedi and using that to get the first parent, than it is a simple loop.

Comment: @user1806756 to clarify, "string" would be `var x = "<div>a</div>";`, DOM node would be `var x = document.getElementsByClassName('div')[0];`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the string into DOM and navigate the tree.

```js
function getAllParents(htmlStr) {
  //find cursor text and replace it with an element we can find
  htmlStr = htmlStr.replace('*cursor*', '<span class="cursor"></span>');
  //make a div we can inject our html into
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  //turn our string into dom we can navigate
  div.innerHTML = htmlStr;
  //find the cursor
  var cur = div.getElementsByClassName("cursor")[0],
    elems = [];
  //loop over all parents
  while (cur) {
    elems.unshift(cur);
    cur = cur.parentNode;
  }
  elems.shift()  //remove our div that holds the html
  elems.pop()    //remove the cursor element we injected
  return elems;  //return the parents
}

console.log(getAllParents("<div><div><span><em>aaa*cursor*aaa</em></span></div></div>"));
console.log(getAllParents("<div><div>*cursor*<span><em>aaaaaa</em></span></div></div>"));
console.log(getAllParents("*cursor*<div><div><span><em>aaaaaa</em></span></div></div>"));
```